# How do I run a command with uxterm after running ~/.bashrc lines in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: .profile

My `~/.profile` file has the following code

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

When I run the following command, `uxterm firefox`

[image: running command]

I do not see any log of the lines of the file `~/.bashrc` on the corresponding `uxterm` window that gets open. I therefore understand the lines of this file are not run whenever I issue the command `uxterm firefox`.

Nonetheless when I just run the command `uxterm`, I do see the mentioned log as you can see on the corresponding attached screenshot

[image: log after running just uxterm].

What should I do to get the lines of `~/.bashrc` run whenever I issue any program with `uxterm+name of the program` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the `-ls` option to make it a login shell, as `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` are only read by login shells.

Comment: I have just tried this command: `uxterm -e -ls firefox`
Even though this command launches a new terminal and runs the lines of the ~/.bashrc according to the log I see, firefox does not get launched.

Comment: That is a separate problem not related to your question here, which was "What should I do to get the lines of ~/.bashrc run [in uxterm]"

Comment: Do you mean that I should ony try `uxterm -ls firefox`? I also tried this and this launched a new uxterm windows and launched Firefox at the same time. Nonetheless ~/.bashrc lines did not get run because I do not see the corresponding log lines on ~/.bashrc.

Comment: If I only run `uxterm -ls`, then I see the ~/.bashrc lines on the new uxterm window. Nonetheless if I add firefox after `uxterm -ls`, then, even though firefox gets launched, no log is posted to the uxterm window. I guess that means ~/.bashrc lines do not get run. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I have also tried `uxterm -e '/bin/bash; firefox'`
Even though this command launches a new uxterm window and it seems the lines of ~/.bashrc get run according the log posted to this new uxterm window, Firefox does not get launched in this case.